# After writing 'Import numpy', I am getting out of python shell to windows shell. Is numpy installed properly?

Tags: numpy, windows-10, command-prompt

After writing 'Import numpy', I am getting out of python shell to windows shell. Is numpy installed properly ? 
I am using Windows 10 64 bit and python 3.7. I updated pip to it's latest version 19.1 and then installed numpy.

I uninstalled and again installed numpy but the result is same as mentioned in the problem summary.

C:\Users\tejas>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/9d/c129d78e6b942303b762ccfdf1f8339de80c5e6021b14ef0c99ec5bdc6aa/numpy-1.16.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.3

C:\Users\tejas>python
Python 3.7.0a2 (v3.7.0a2:f7ac4fe, Oct 17 2017, 17:06:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import numpy

C:\Users\tejas>

Expected result is, after typing 'import numpy', control should not get out of python shell to windows shell. It should stay in python shell itself as I am not exiting the python shell.

Comment: Do you get any error message? Did you try looking for logfiles?

Comment: I don't get any error message. It is getting out of python interpreter to windows shell automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I updated python from version 3.7.0 to 3.7.3 which is the latest version available at the time of writing this answer.

Now, numpy is imported successfully.